# Merge Arraylists inside an ArrayLists of Arraylists

Tags: java, arraylist

I have arraylist the has 30 arraylists
i want to keep the the first 6 array lists and add
7th to the 1st
8th to the 2nd
9th to the 3rd .. and so on
meaning that the 6th arraylist from the current one will added to it

Comment: Please post any code you have attempted to write.

Comment: Problem Statement Not clear...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following method should do the trick:

```
public static <T> void merge(ArrayList<ArrayList<T>> arrayLists) {
    int blockSize = 6;
    for(int i=blockSize; i<arrayLists.size(); i++) {
        arrayLists.get(i % blockSize).addAll(arrayLists.get(i));
    }
    arrayLists.subList(blockSize, arrayLists.size()).clear();
}
```

You can convert `blockSize` to the method parameter if you like.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfect